# Laravel: Validate a name input in a form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, laravel, validation

I'm using laravel and have a form.How do I validate a name for a input field within a form. so that random numbers cannot be entered in the the field.  It is just a simple input field:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
   <label>First Name: </label>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
   <input type="text" class ="span3" name="first_name" id="first_name" 
      required/><br><br>
</div>
```

I have validated an email through an example I saw and it is validates as soon you leave that input box after typing instead of waiting to click the submit button.

> **How would I be able to do that? Meaning, as soon as the user leaves the input field after typing in something(a number), it validates and
>   says something(like 'please enter a proper name').** I'm not sure if
>   its requires using the regex or not, and how would I be able to get my desired result.

My code for the email is as:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <label>Email: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <input type="email" class ="span3" id="email" name="email" value="{{ 
              old('email') }}" required/><br><br>
         @if ($errors->has('email'))
           <span class="help-block">
             <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
           </span>
        @endif
   </div>
</div>
```

I was able to do this from an example and this validates the email as soon as a user types.

Comment: This is not the complete code. For real-time form validation, some sort of Javascript is required. Please update the question

Comment: @WesleyPeeters how would it be done without the real time validation?

Comment: I've posted a rather long answer for you haha! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate a request in Laravel, you can do two different things:

---

### Option 1. The validator

Let's say your form is being posted to the method `test` in a controller:

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    //
}
```

What you could do in this method, is utilize the validator like this:

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);
}
```

A complete list of validation rules can be found [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#available-validation-rules). Using this will throw a bunch of errors back, when the validation rules fail. Instructions on how to show these errors in a view can be found [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).

---

### Option 2. Form request validation

Another option would be to use request classes. These request classes can be generated with a artisan command. The signature for this command is as follows:

`php artisan make:request {NAME OF YOUR REQUEST}`

For the sake of this answer, I'll use a request class named `TestRequest`. After generation, the class will look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class TestRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Let's quickly break it down.

**The `authorize` function:**
This function does what it's name sounds like. It determines if a user is authorized to make this request. A small example is this, on a website with a guest book, everyone is allowed to post a comment, so you'd do `return true`:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

But, if you want a user to only be allowed if he has certain permissions, you can also check that from this function. However, the `authorize` function ***MUST*** return a boolean (true/false). To see how this is done, read up on Laravel's gates [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#gates).

**The `rules` function:**
In this function, validation rules for the fields can be set. These rules are the same as mentioned before when talking about `the validator`. A small example is this:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email'
        ];
    }
```

Where the key of the array element is the `name` attribute of the form, and the value is a list of the validation rules, divided by a `|`.

I suggest you read up on Laravel's validation in general, which can be done [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation).

I hope this was in any means helpful. Cheers!

Comment: I understand it, but how do I write the regex expression. would it be like this: 'first_name' => 'required|/[a-z][A-Z]/|first_name'  ? couldn't properly find it in the laravel docs link u provided

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, You can use `focusout` method as soon as the input field `#first_name` was out of focus. https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

If you want to check if the given value provided is valid or not, You can use [regular expression] just like what you did on your `email` input field:

Here's a given example:

```
$('#first_name').focusout(function() {
    var sValue = $(this).val();
    var sEmailPattern = /[a-z][A-Z]$/i;
    var bCheckValue = sEmailPattern.test(sValue);
    console.log(bCheckValue);

    if (bCheckValue !== true) {
        alert('please enter a proper name');
        return false;
    }

    // Rest of code ....

});
```

Hope this helps for your case.

Comment: i tried placing it inside a script tag after the input, it didn't work..did I place it wrong?

Comment: Hmm...Can you `console.log(sValue)`?